# Adding iFrame module has messed up my ContentPanes styling

Tags: css, module, dotnetnuke

Ever since I added a iFrame module to my website my main ContentPanes styling has changed.

The changes include a loss of padding to the main ContentPane and only on some pages I have lost the background colour of the main ContentPane(it should be gray buts its transparent instead). I didn't edit these individual pages so I assume its because of the iFrame module?

**Why does this happen and how can I readd my padding and background colour to the main Content pane without having to edit each individual page?**

*Note: I have since removed the iframe module but that hasn't fixed the errors with the ContentPane.*

**EDIT:** [Link to padding error](http://www.exds.com.au/) (Nowtice how the "12d Model Skilled Migrant Training for 2012" Div has no padding)
**EDIT:** [Link to background error](http://www.exds.com.au/Support/64bitcomputersWindows7and12dModel.aspx) (Notice how the "64bit Computers, Windows7 and 12d Model" has no gray BK)

Comment: @zenkaty ok see the edit for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

On the first example, there is no padding in the CSS - you will have to actually apply padding to the template. Looks like you are using inline styles for this? So just give it `style="padding:20px;"` or whatever you want there.

On the second one, the background style is missing. On the first one, it has `style="background-color:#f3f3f3;"` - you just need to apply the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Using inline style means I am going to have to go through each page and apply that style right? Is there a broad sweeping changing I can make? I know it involves changing the class/id CSS but I dont know where in DNN I can do this and more importantly which class/id I use: I think its .dnn_content but not sure

Comment: I went to Admin - Site Settings then Stylesheet editor and I added this CSS "#dnn_ContentPane {padding: 10px; background-color: #f3f3f3; }" but the css is never applied(nor written when I look in firebug)

Comment: Can't you change the template that all those pages are made from? Ideally you would put it in the CSS, but there is no useful class on the divs you need to apply to padding to. Search your templates for "background-color:#f3f3f3" - that appears inline on the div that needs to have padding. Really, you should remove the inline style there and replace it with a class that you can then style remotely from the CSS sheet.

Comment: thanks for the advice. How do I 'change the template those pages are made from'? I'm experienced with HTML,CSS & Javascript but DNN is new to me. Do you mean the change the module? Where can I access the template/module for those pages?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with DNN specifically, might have to wait for an expert to come along!